# Switch styles on an OpenStreetMap server using Mapnik, PostGIS etc

Tags: openstreetmap, tilemill, mapnik

I have created an OpenStreetMap server using this guide: [switch to osm](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/) it's very good and works like a charm. I have also been able to add a new theme using [TileMill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) and [osm-brigth](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright)

However, I now want to be able to switch between two themes, [osm-bright](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright) and [osm-night](https://github.com/cybercomsweden/osm-night). Is this an apache question or is there a way to modify mapnik to be able to get a parameter from for example openlayers to switch between these two themes?

Gratefull for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install "OSM Night" style like the first one into a separate directory, download all required files.
2. Produce XML out of MML with `carto -l project.mml > osm-night.xml`, like you probably did with osm-bright.
3. Edit `/etc/renderd.conf` adding a second style section, like for osm-bright, but with names and paths to osm-night.
4. Restart renderd and apache2.

After that you will have two set of tiles generated: e.g. `/osm-bright/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` and `/osm-night/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`. Add both of them as tile layers to your OpenLayers page, and add a layer switcher. (I use Leaflet and not sure how it's done in OL).